# Tring to do text data augmentation from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-augmentation

I was trying to do text data augmentation using Easy Data Augmentation techniques. I have a function EDA.
Here is an example of the function.

Code:

```
test_sentence = 'The words "from the rotten head of the fish" describe our decay and 
helplessness. What kind of wind is this?'
augment_sentence = EDA(test_sentence, 1).eda(num_aug=4)
print(augment_sentence)
```

Output:
[['the words from the rotten head of the fish distinguish our decay and helplessness what tolerant of wind is this', 1], ['the words from head of the fish describe our decay and helplessness kind of wind is this', 1], ['the words from the rotten head of the angle describe our decay and helplessness what sort of wind is this', 1], ['the words from the rotten head of describe fish the our decay and helplessness what this of wind is kind', 1]]

The above is an example of single-line text. I have a CSV file and I tried to do augmentation on the CSV file where I tried to read each row of the CSV file and put it into the EDA function.
But I was getting an error saying

> 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

code

```
from csv import reader
# open file in read mode
with open('c1.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
  # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
   csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
   # Iterate over each row in the csv using reader object
   for row in csv_reader:
      # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
       augment_sentence = EDA(row, 1).eda(num_aug=4)
       print(augment_sentence)
```

[Scrrenshot of Code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQwCP.png)

here is my  EDA function:

[here is the EDA function](https://github.com/jasonwei20/eda_nlp/blob/master/code/eda.py)

Comment: Even if your `csv` have only one sentence per row, you still need to access the first (and only) index of that row. Try `EDA(row[0], 1).eda(num_aug=4)`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but didtn't work then i tried EDA(row[-1], 1).eda(num_aug=4) now its working. Thank you so much.